Do fluids move from areas of higher to lower total pressure or static pressure?
Basically title. I was taught that 2 types of pressures exist, static and dynamic, but most of the nomenclature just talks about "pressure" by itself. So when we say fluid move from high to low pressure, are we talking about static pressure or total pressure? It would be strange if it was total pressure because then there would be no movement of fluid in absence of friction.

Total pressure is the same thing as static pressure.

@ChetMiller Is total pressure not the sum of static and dynamic pressure?

It depends on whose terminology you use.  I just call pressure ... pressure.  In my terminology, pressure is what you call static pressure.  I don't like referring to the kinetic energy per unit volume as "dynamic pressure."  I think it only confuses students.

It's the static pressure (for incompressible, athermal, steady, invscid windflow) since the Bernoulli's equation's $^1$ RHS
$$P_{static}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2+\rho gh=P_{total}=const.\tag{1}$$
is a constant of motion (along a streamline) denoting conservation of energy. So almost stationary wind in a high static pressure region flows towards the low static pressure region accelerating from the pressure gradient. By the time it reaches the depression, it is moving with significant kinetic energy (density), the sum total remaining same.
I find the distinction between total and static pressure superfluous in that they both are pressures and it's only the relative difference which is measurable anyway.
Windflow in nature occurs under thermal gradients so the equation as stated above isn't directly applicable to large scale weather phenomenon.

$^1$ pressure $P$, density of fluid $\rho$, acceleration due to gravity $g$, height above the ground $h$, velocity of fluid $v$.

This is a little like asking if an object moves in the direction of a force. The acceleration is in the direction of a force, not the velocity.
An example of dynamic pressure is a hose being squirted onto a sidewalk. The pressure is high inside the hose. But once in free flight, the pressure is $1$ atmosphere.
When the stream hits the sidewalk, the sidewalk exerts a force on the layer of water in contact. That layer exerts a force on the next layer, and so on. The force per unit area is pressure.
Each layer is decelerated a bit in the forward direction and accelerated a bit sideways.
As the water leaves the region near the stream, the forces drop off to $0$ and the pressure returns to atmospheric.
